# Optocoupler as switch

Tags: transistors, switches, relay, power-electronics, analog-switch

I am trying to use an optocoupler as an ON/OFF switch for an analog circuit. When high/ON voltage is applied at input, the output side should be short circuited. Otherwise it should act as OFF/open circuit. The problem is that there's significant voltage drop across the transistor  when it should be acting as ON with minimal voltage drop across itself (upto 2V is tolerable). The intermediate circuitry ensures maximum possible voltage across a wildly varying load while limiting the current to 2mA.

I had earlier used an SRD-05VDC-SL-C relay board which was near-ideal. Want to replace the bulky module to minimize the overall size of the project.

Kindly suggest solutions or possible designs.
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please post a schematic including component values.

Comment: Sorry, but nobody knows what's the analog signal to be switched . I mean minimum momentary voltage against GND, max. momentary voltage against GND, current, frequency range, allowed voltage drop in the switch. And what's the signal which should control the switch? And is the galvanic isolation a must and how fast should the switching happen? You should reveal something essential of the application to get something useful. "Fairly low power conditions" reveals not enough.

Answer (score 1):

> *When high/ON voltage is applied at input, the output side should be
> short circuited.*

A short circuit sounds like an attractive requirement specification but, it's an impossibility (or a pipe-dream); you have to be practical and realistic and accept that it won't be an ideal short-circuit. That means you have to design your requirements to suit what can be done.

> *Otherwise it should act as OFF/open circuit.*

It's the same sort of story for this requirement.

> *Kindly suggest solutions or possible designs.*

You need to write a decent and realizable specification.

> *The problem is that there's significant voltage drop across the
> transistor when it should be acting as ON with minimal voltage drop
> across itself.*

Yes, that sounds about right but, you have to establish what is good-enough for achieving your aims. Nobody can help you without you producing a reasonable requirements specification. Please also include switching speed and open-circuit capacitance of the "switch".

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. A drop of upto 2V is acceptable across the transistor. Also, at no point does the current exceed 2mA due to current limiter/voltage regulator intermediate circuitry.